# SQL Server 2008 R2 View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, view

I want to know the best way to create a SQL view to track the activity on accounts from letters sent out for a handful of customers. I have list of activity codes I am filtering on in my where clause, however these accounts already have activity codes associated with them. I want the view to only show new activity codes for an account after the date when we send out the letters.

Here is my query :

```
select
    *
from 
    rsbi.dbo.EndOfYearSettlementLetter eys
left join 
    collectorjournal cj on eys.LN_ACCTNO = cj.CJ_ACCTNO
where
    cj.CJ_ACTIVITY in  ('3CO', 'CCO', 'CIO', 'CMC', 'CMO', 'LFC', 'TC2', 'TCL', 'TR', 'TRR2')
```

Comment: It's hard to provide guidance without knowing your table structure(s). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and provide expected result because reading does not all the time relay the right information

Comment: Ideally since we haven't sent out the letters. My view should return 0 rows.